# Not quite ERC721 or ERC21

Tags: erc-20, erc-721

I have a problem that I'm really stuck with so I'm coming to the experts:)

I have a personal project I'm working on. I'm minting tokens in large batches, once a condition is met, a new batch of tokens is minted and any older batches are worthless.

This isn't quite ERC20 since a token in batch 1 has a different batchID than a token in batch2, but it also isnt really in the spirit of ERC721 since each token in a batch is identical.

What do i do? I thought of potentially giving tokens some kind of lifespan but that get's convoluted. Is there any obvious solution that I'm missing?

Comment: You may be interested in [ERC-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155), which is like a combination of ERC-20 and ERC-721.

Comment: Gonna need a not more detail and an actual question to help with an answer. But most literally, what you do is you hire somebody that has launched project before and has experience and reputation.